# Disable dynamic queue creation

Tags: activemq-classic

When sending a message to a queue in ActiveMQ (e.g. using `JmsTemplate.convertAndSend()`) that is not configured the queue is dynamically created (on the fly).

Is it possible to have an exception thrown instead (e.g. if the queue wasn't create explicitly on the broker)?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to have an exception thrown if the queue wasn't create explicitly on the broker. JMS destinations are automatically created for users who have the `admin` permission. Therefore, any user for which you don't want the broker to automatically create JMS destinations should *not* be in a role with the `admin` permission. Here's a sample configuration:

```xml
<broker> 
  .. 
    <plugins> 
      .. 
      <authorizationPlugin> 
        <map> 
          <authorizationMap> 
            <authorizationEntries> 
              <authorizationEntry queue="myQueue" read="consumers" write="producers" admin="admins" /> 
            </authorizationEntries> 
          </authorizationMap> 
        </map> 
      </authorizationPlugin> 
      .. 
    </plugins> 
  .. 
</broker>
```

In this configuration any users in the `admins` role will have the `admin` permission and the broker will automatically create JMS destinations for these users.